# Apache Proxy URL exclusion wont work

Tags: centos, apache-2.4, httpd, mod-proxy, proxypass

we are running an Apache/2.4.6 on CentOS.
i am trying to setup an Proxy Endpoint on the Apache which is passing requests to internal Servers (target servers). So far the Endpoint does what it should, except for the Part where certain URLs should be excluded. I have the following config:

```
proxypass /#/b/c/excluded/url/ !
proxypass / http://myhost/
proxypassreverse / http://myhost/
```

in my opinion, requests which has the following URL shouldnt be passed:

- http://myhost/#/b/c/excluded/url/ -> 403 forbidden

while everything else should be passed. ( including /#/b/c/ but not /#/b/c/excluded/url )

- http://myhost/#/b/c -> 200
- http://myhost/#/b -> 200
- http://myhost/something/completely/different
- etc.

but apparently the Target-Server does an redirect when i try to access the excluded URL, which means he is getting the full request.

how do i block the request for the certain URL on my proxy? The provided method doesnt seem to work or im doing something wrong without noticing. Might the "#" in the URL be the problem?

BR, rolski

Comment: tried another few things: 

```
<Proxy "http://myhost/#/b/c/excluded/url">
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
</Proxy>
```
Doesnt work, does nothing. When adding an * instead of the URL i want to block, it completely blocks access to the proxy for this vhost. Nothing i ever have put into this directive ever has matched. Its either all or nothing.  

Escaping the Pound-sign with an Backslash also didnt work.